# Process: kernel_task over 700mb memory

Tags: macos, memory, kernel

Does anyone know why the process "kernel_task" is using up so much memory and how to fix it? I have a Macmini6,1

I tried to delete .plist files from folder bellow, but the problem still continued:

/System/Library/Extensions/IOPlatformPluginFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin.kext/Contents/Resources/

[image: process][image: finder]

Comment: Why did you delete exactly those files? BTW 700 MB memory consumption is completely normal...

Comment: I have 450 Mb with 2% CPU and it does not bother me!

Comment: How much RAM do you have in your Mac? And what problem are you trying to solve by reducing the amount of RAM allocated to kernel_task? It is generally a bad idea to randomly mess with files under /System, you could end up with a Mac that can't boot.